# What if someone asks me "May I use the seat?"?

Tags: phrase-request

I was sitting in a coffee shop alone (just with myself). The table I sat had two chair. Then a man came and asked me "May I?", and he pointed the chair which was in front of me.
What should I answer if I meet the situation again? Shall I answer "Is not occupied", or "You can take it"? Or another?

Comment: I'd say: "please, go ahead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to give them the seat, you can respond with *may*:

> 1. You may./You may use it.

This might be a little formal. More casually, you can say

> 2. Yes.
> 3. Go ahead.
> 4. Sure./Sure thing.

There are many other options.

Your options work too.

> 5. It is not occupied.
> 6. You can take it.

In 5, you need a subject like *it* or *the seat*. 5 also seems a little stiff, so I don't recommend it.